# Can JW Player load external plugins instead of from their CDN?

Tags: plugins, cdn, jwplayer

Tiny question: Can JW Player load external plugins instead of from their CDN? Basically, I just want to host my own plugins. I'm looking for something I can add to the FlashVars parameters, most likely the URL to the plugin SWF. This has been bugging me for a few days, I haven't been able to find anything on the interwebs about this topic. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally possible!

Just reference your plugin as http://www.mydomain.com/myplugin.swf or myplugin.swf and the player will accept it and load it. You can even mix and match:

```
plugins=hd-1,http://www.mydomain.com/myplugin.swf,captions-1
```

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTailVideo